# Adding and subtracting within cells containing specific text

Tags: sum, addition, contains, subtraction, sumifs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhXaY.png)I am working on a sheet that a cell would contain a 2 Letter code along with a value, for example, CE # (where # is an actual value) and CT #. For context CE is Earned Time and CT is Time Taken. If I have row 2 as CE 4 and row 3 as CT 2, I would like to have an cell showing that my end result would equal 2.

```
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| CE       | CE 4     |
| CT       | CT 2     |
|          |          |
| TOTAL    | C  2     |
```

I have gotten this far as to add up the CE values, but cannot figure out how to delete the CT values.

```
=SUM(IF((LEFT(S9:S373,2))="CE",(--RIGHT((IF(S9:S373="",0,S9:S373)),2)),0))
```